# Create new file on server with shared directory (java)

Tags: java, windows, file, shared-directory

I am not familiar with Windows shared folders, but here is what I have:

```
filePath = //server/TEMP/ **(1)**
```

server = another machine. TEMP = shared folder.

If I open this line with Explorer it goes to

```
http://server/TEMP/
```

and I can see list of files and create new.

If I change

```
filePath = \\server\TEMP\ **(2)**
```

(slashes replacement) I CAN'T open this directory.

in java code (1.6) I have

```
File f = new File(filePath);
```

where filePath can be (1) or (2) - no matters, after creating the File object its `.toString()` gives me

> \\server\TEMP\ **(2)**

which CAN'T execute `.createNewFile()` with this exception:

> java.io.IOException: The network path was not found   at
>
> java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)  at
>
> java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)

How to say to java not to convert my slashes? or how to create file without java.io.File?

Thanks,
Roman.

Comment: Actually this is not slashes problem. http://server/TEMP/ and \\server\TEMP\ even uses different protocol (htto and samba), so your problem far deeper from slashes

Comment: So, as I understand default File slashes will use samba to create files on remote folders, right? And how to create file with http then?

Comment: Not only slashes. File always use OS filesystem calls for working with files. So opening \\server\share delegates such call for open file in OS. This wiil work on Windows and fail on Linux. For working with http you need absolutely different approach, for example use Apache HttpClient library or so. But i'm think before you start solve java problems you need really understand whats going on in general. I.e. usually you can't create file on remote http file. May be you remote server has WebDAV installed?